# onRequestPermissionsResult() triggered in Activity not Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-permissions

I am calling `requestPermissions()` in my Fragment and it's fragment implementation of that function (I'm not calling `activity.requestPermission()`). I have `onRequestPermissionsResult()` in both parent Activity and Fragment. After calling for permission from Fragment it triggers wrong `onRequestPermissionsResult()`. Why is that happening

Fragments call for permission:

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
    return if (item?.itemId == R.id.createNewChat) {
        if (activity.hasReadContactsPermission()) {
            startActivity(Intent(activity, PhoneBookActivity::class.java))
        } else {
            requestPermissions(
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS),
                Constants.MY_PERMISSIONS_READ_CONTACT
            )
        }
        true
    } else {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

Fragments `onRequestPermissionsResult()`:

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    permissions: Array<String>,
    grantResults: IntArray
) {
    when (requestCode) {
        Constants.MY_PERMISSIONS_READ_CONTACT -> {
            if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                startActivity(Intent(activity, PhoneBookActivity::class.java))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Activities `onRequestPermissionsResult()`:

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    permissions: Array<String>,
    grantResults: IntArray
) {
    when (requestCode) {
        Constants.MY_PERMISSIONS_MULTIPLE -> {
            if (grantResults.all { it == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED }) {
                startService(Intent(this, RegisterDeviceTokenTask::class.java))
                if (smartServiceBound) {
                    smart113Service!!.onMainActivityStarted()
                } else {
                    requestPermissionsUtil(
                        requiredPermissions,
                        Constants.MY_PERMISSIONS_MULTIPLE
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I could probably listen for this permission check in Activity but requestCode changes when it moves from Fragment to Activity and I don't want to mess with that.

What is the solution to get `onRequestPermissionResult()` triggered in Fragment ?

Comment: try using `fragment.requestPermissions()`

Comment: I've tried, I found a solution after 2 days! Was missing 
`else -> super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)` in Acitivties `onRequestPermissionsResult()`